# How to keep pop up open and after running php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

HI i am developing my website and want my login forms to be on pop up windows, as i am stuck because my pop get closed after running my php script on the pop window. due to which i am unable to echo error messages on the same popup (like incorrect password and user already exists).

I am using php 5.4 through easy php and due to the same issue i ended up creating pages instead of pop ups, can anyone help me with demos to understand as how this can be worked

Comment: what have you done? share some code.

Comment: Reopen the popup and populate the values and then do what you have to do

Comment: Windows/popups dont close on their own - they close when something directs them to close. It's a simple matter of not performing the close action until its actually wanted. Entirely trivial if you've already developed your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax for achieving this functionality.

Here's the reference for best example:

http://www.codingcage.com/2015/11/ajax-login-script-with-jquery-php-mysql.html